# Подключение файлов Less bootstrap-проекта при работе с Gulp

Tags: bootstrap, gulp, less

Настроил Gulp для работы с проектом Bootstrap. Возник вопрос, как при этом использовать и `less` файлы Bootstrap, так чтобы в `style.less` были доступны переменные и `mixin`-ы.

Пока не придумал ничего лучшего, как импортировать `bootstrap.less` целиком в файл `style.less`. Файл `style.css` получился очень большим...

А какова стандартная практика? Что где подключать? Нет ли плагина для удаления неиспользуемого в проекте лишнего css кода?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-uncss

Comment: @greybutton Спасибо за помощь. Этот плагин видимо то, что надо. Стандартные настройки подключения нашел на: https://itchief.ru/lessons/bootstrap-3/bootstrap-3-configuring-the-platform-using-variables-in-less